# is a field but used is used like a type

Tags: c#

```
DataTable dtcol = new DataTable();
string strdttype = cmbDttype.SelectedItem.ToString();
dtcol.TableName = txtDtname.Text;
dtxsd.Columns.Add(txtCname.Text, typeof(strdttype));
dtcol.WriteXmlSchema("@D:\Example\exampledt.xsd");
```

I am writing the above code to fill datatable with columns,here I am getting the column names from txtCname and I am selecting the datatype of that column from Combobox `cmbDttype`.

```
 dtxsd.Columns.Add(txtCname.Text, typeof(strdttype)); //In this line I am getting error strdttype is a field but used is used like a type.
```

`txtDtname` carries the tablename of that datatable.
From the last line it will write the Schema into exampledt but existing datatable in xsd file is missing and newly created datatable appears.

Answer (score 5):

You should provide **type name** to [typeof operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (instead of variable name). Your `strdttype` has type of string, so correct code will be:

```
dtxsd.Columns.Add(txtCname.Text, typeof(string));
```

Another option - get type of variable:

```
dtxsd.Columns.Add(txtCname.Text, strdttype.GetType());
```

Comment: when I am writing that Schema into xsd for creating a datatable already existing datatable is deleting always newly created datatable is showing in xsd file.

Answer (score 1):

Use of typeof is wrong here. You need to give ClassName instead of an object here. To get type of object try second line.

```
 typeof(ClassName);
 someVariable.GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two different errors in your code. one is quite obvious, but other is conditional.

1. You are using typeof operator on a variable instead of type. typeof
   operator provides the type of underlying datatype so the correct
   usage is

   ```
   var t = typeof(string);
   ```

   or

   ```
   var tt = typeof(int);
   ```

   If you want to get the type of a variable then you should use GetType()
   method as follows:

   ```
   dtxsd.Columns.Add(txtCname.Text, strdttype.GetType());
   ```
2. I think you have a combobox for selecting the datatype, and depending on the selection your column type would be decided. If it so then even if you use GetType method it will always return string as your variable strdttype is string type. I think in that case you should use following statement

   ```
       dtxsd.Columns.Add(txtCname.Text, Type.GetType(strdttype));
   ```

   Where the values in your combobox should be in following format:
   "System.Int32", "System.String", "System.Int64", . . . and so on.

Regards,

Nitin Joshi